# Auto partition a table in MySQL after reaching a million records

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, database-performance

I'm using a table that has more than 20 million records and running query is taking a significant amount of time. Can I have a definition or statement, saying if the sequence number reaches a million do a partition with name predefined naming syntax like table_name_i where i keeps on incrementing.

Table definition is like below:

```
Table name - CHIP_DETAILS
Columns - 
  SEQ_NO - INT(10) - Auto Increment
  CHIP_ID - Varchar(16)
  TOKEN - VARCHAR(16)
  CHIP_BLOB (TINY BLOB)
  TOKEN BLOB (TINY BLOB)
  GENERATED_TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP
  USER_ID - INT(10)
```

---

```
MYSQL version - MySQL server 5.5.23 
OS - Windows 7 Home Premium - 64 Bit 
RAM - 8 Gigs 
Processor - Intel i5 2.53
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how partitioning the table into multiple tables is going to increase performance, unless you can distribute those tables over different hardware, like different servers or at least diferent hard disks. At least if your queries need to operate on the whole table. If only a fraction of the table is sufficient for most queries, then identifying the criteria describing that fraction might be better than simply splitting at arbitrary points.

Comment: @MvG - I'll have queries that need to hit the entire table and splitting data would make the fetch much faster than looking after million records, and this is what I thought. May be I was mislead by the word partition, but would love to hear any techniques or tricks that would help me execute my queries much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you partition the table into say *n* distinct tables, then each of them will only contain one *n*<sup>th</sup> of the data, so you can expect queries to be faster by a factor of up to *n*. But for queries which have to process all the data, you'll need to operate on each of these *n* tables, which means you'll have *n* such queries. In the best case, this brings you back to the original performance. In practice, the constant overhead required to prepare a query for execution will be executed *n* times instead of once, so you'll almost certainly be degrading performance.

Database engines usually are designed to cope quite well with large amounts of data, and 20 million records isn't really that much. So **manually redistributing the data isn't likely to be helpful.** Instead, you should check to make sure that you have [suitable indices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization-indexes.html) to access only those portions of the database you actually need to access. The table may be really huge, but as long as you only access a small portion of it, your queries will still be fast. Have a look at the output of the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html) command for one of the queries you consider too slow, to see where you might need other indices. [Rewriting the queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-optimization.html), e.g. to make better use of these indices, might help as well. [Optimizing a database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization.html) is a complex subject, and requires more knowledge of what you're actually trying to do. One crucial information is the ratio between reads and writes.

As I wrote in a comment above, splitting your table only makes sense if you can place the different parts on different hard disks, so that they can be accessed in parallel. In that case, you will want to explore the [MySQL partitioning features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) in order to let MySQL do the splitting in such a way as to maximize the use of parallel access.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning a table should be done via column values, for example date.  If you put a months worth of data into each partition, a query that covers only 2 months of data (and this needs to be made explicit in a filter on the query), only 2 partitions need to be included by the optimiser to give the results.  Unless you partition on a column in the data (for exaple month), and use an arbitrary non data based partition key like row_id, how will the optimiser know which partitions the data it needs to answer the query resides in?  It will have to refer to all partitions, then stitch all the data back together - making the query even slower than if you didn't partition.